# How to read data with multiple header blocks

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read in SoDAR data files into python which would be easy if it only had one header block. However it has 4 header rows every 40 lines. Additionally the date and time are in one of the header rows.

Can anyone help me read-in just the data and the date/time (I am assuming I will have to read this file twice for both pieces of info).

The file is a .dat file which is space delimited.

#### Example data:

```
SJSU_Sodar_DiabloCanyon 04/21/2013 00:00:00 TO 04/21/2013 00:10:00 VR1.44  4400   150 100    60    15     0     0
600 5 20 7 0 0 25 15 64 1000 6 5 5 -600 600 -600 600 -400 400 0 10 359 100 63 1 80 7 1 0 0 59 2 12 6 14 6 0 0 0 5 5
3 COMPONENT 37HTS ZENITH 16-16 ARA 359 SEPANG 090 MXHT 0 UNOISE    15 VNOISE    13 WNOISE    21 ANTENNA STATUS:   OK AC STATUS:N/A BATTV:12.67 TEMPC: 3.9
  HT    SPD  DIR      W    SDW   IW   GSPD GDIR      U    SDU   NU   IU SNRU      V    SDV   NV   IV SNRV   NW SNRW
 200  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    5   15    5  99.99  99.99    3   12    5    3    6
 195  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    3   15    5  99.99  99.99    0   12    5    2    6
 190  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    2   15    5  99.99  99.99    4   12    5    8    6
 185  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    2   15    5  99.99  99.99    1   12    5    5    6
 180  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    0   15    5  99.99  99.99    2   12    5    3    6
 175  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    0   15    5  99.99  99.99    3   12    5    1    6
 170  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    0   15    5  99.99  99.99    4   12    5    4    6
 165  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    0   15    5  99.99  99.99    1   12    5    7    6
 160  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    1   15    5  99.99  99.99    5   12    5    5    6
 155  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    1   15    5  99.99  99.99    3   13    5    5    6
 150  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   22  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    1   15    5  99.99  99.99    1   13    5    6    6
 145  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   22  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    1   15    5  99.99  99.99    0   13    5    3    6
 140  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   22  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    2   15    5  99.99  99.99    1   12    5    5    6
 135  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    2   15    5  99.99  99.99    1   12    5    4    6
 130  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   22  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    4   16    5  99.99  99.99    2   13    5    1    6
 125  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   22  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    3   16    5  99.99  99.99    1   13    5    5    6
 120  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   22  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    0   16    5  99.99  99.99    5   13    5    7    6
 115  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   22  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    2   16    5  99.99  99.99    2   13    5    4    6
 110  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   23  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    1   16    5  99.99  99.99    0   14    5    7    6
 105   1.54  137   0.28   1.13   27   2.32  146  -1.02   0.36   16   20    6   1.15   0.80   16   18    6   16    6
 100   1.24   93   0.16   0.75   33   3.53  118  -1.24   0.61   36   24    6   0.09   0.42   34   26    6   32    7
 95   0.77   70   0.09   0.58   40   3.06  140  -0.73   0.51   48   30    7  -0.25   0.57   46   32    7   42    7
 90   0.63   80  -0.06   0.55   39   3.42   84  -0.62   0.46   38   34    7  -0.10   0.60   45   37    7   41    7
  85   0.33   13   0.00   0.55   41   3.11  239  -0.08   0.41   49   39    7  -0.32   0.54   37   36    7   61    9
  80   0.62  352   0.06   0.42   43   3.02   30   0.08   0.43   60   41    8  -0.62   0.62   30   33    6   57    9
  75   0.96  354   0.06   0.45   46   3.50  305   0.08   0.51   53   42    7  -0.96   0.75   26   35    6   61    9
  70   0.80  318   0.03   0.41   58   4.13    1   0.52   0.36   57   51    8  -0.60   0.70   41   42    7   69   10
  65   1.23  273   0.01   0.33   86   3.25  263   1.23   0.40   68   75    9  -0.08   0.49   63   61    8   83   13
  60   1.40  262   0.00   0.39  118   2.77  268   1.39   0.38   83  103   10   0.18   0.39   71   78    9   98   15
  55   0.66  267   0.05   0.26  152   2.14  356   0.66   0.29   93  129   12   0.02   0.33   90   97   11  103   17
  50   1.12  260  -0.09   0.51  173   2.61  243   1.11   0.34  100  134   12   0.18   0.54   95  114   11  102   19
  45   0.44  345   0.07   0.32  214   4.70   26   0.11   0.33   99  153   12  -0.42   0.56   91  158   12  105   19
  40   0.37   15   0.03   0.25  268   2.38    0  -0.10   0.34  101  172   13  -0.36   0.55  103  208   14  105   22
  35   0.10  144  -0.03   0.30  270   1.88  191  -0.06   0.29   94  169   13   0.08   0.45   92  189   13  100   22
  30   0.40   40   0.03   0.32  241   2.50  107  -0.26   0.37   90  175   12  -0.30   0.35   92  185   12   98   19
  25   0.62   70   0.00   0.38  234   2.75   76  -0.58   0.37   96  190   13  -0.20   0.40   94  171   12  102   21
  20   1.42   78  -0.07   0.35  333   4.40   82  -1.39   0.43  103  284   14  -0.28   0.40   95  232   11  104   18
SJSU_Sodar_DiabloCanyon 04/21/2013 00:10:00 TO 04/21/2013 00:20:00 VR1.44  4400   150   100    60    15     0     0
600 5 20 7 0 0 25 15 64 1000 6 5 5 -600 600 -600 600 -400 400 0 10 359 100 63 1 80 7 1 0 0 59 2 12 6 14 6 0 0 0 5 5
3 COMPONENT 37HTS ZENITH 16-16 ARA 359 SEPANG 090 MXHT 0 UNOISE    15 VNOISE    12 WNOISE    21 ANTENNA STATUS:   OK AC STATUS:N/A BATTV:12.67 TEMPC: 3.8
  HT    SPD  DIR      W    SDW   IW   GSPD GDIR      U    SDU   NU   IU SNRU      V    SDV   NV   IV SNRV   NW SNRW
 200  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    0   15    5  99.99  99.99    3   13    5    1    6
 195  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    2   15    5  99.99  99.99    1   12    5    1    6
 190  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    1   15    5  99.99  99.99    0   12    5    1    6
 185  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99   21  99.99 9999  99.99  99.99    1   15    5  99.99  99.99    2   12    5    0    6
```

Comment: What are you wanting to read it into? List, etc.

Comment: preferably an array but it really doesn't matter.  I can handle the data once I get it into a list, array, or dictionary(s).

Comment: Do all 4 headers have the date time or just the first?

Comment: the date is the same but I will be reading in multiple files which have different dates.  the times are all different

Comment: I should clarify; Are all 4 header lines the same? Meaning is the date time 'field' in each line? Regardless if the actual dates are the same...

Comment: no.  The first line of the four has the date time fields.  But each header block has the same format

Comment: @Cwilliams Is there anything that 1) Can identify the starting point of the 4 line header or 2) Is common to all header lines? It would be really useful if you could provide sample data as currently any answers would have to make assumptions which may be quickly invalidated for your use-case based on your actual data.

Comment: @JonClements I have revised my post to show the first 40+ lines of data

Comment: @Cwilliams okay thanks - that's useful... I've remove the redundant sample data and added the main `python` tag so it gets more attention

Comment: Did you try something that didn't work?

Answer (score 4):

If it's always 4 lines header, 40 lines block, 4 lines header etc.. then you can adjust the following:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle, izip

with open('input_file.data') as fin:
    lines = iter(lambda limit=cycle([4, 40]): [line.split() for line in islice(fin, next(limit))], [])
    for header, data in izip(*[iter(lines)] * 2):
        print header[0][1] # date
        print data[0] # first row of data under header
```

If lines beginning with a digit is a more suitable check than fixed sized chunks, then:

```
with open('input_file.dat') as fin:
    grouped = groupby(fin, lambda L: L.lstrip()[0].isdigit())
    lines = ([line.split() for line in g] for k, g in grouped)
    for header, data in izip(*[iter(lines)] * 2):
        print header[0][1]
```